# How can we use Activity.finishActivity(REQUEST_CODE) with onActivityResult deprecated?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I want to use the new way to start an activity and get the result back because `Activity.startActvityForResult` is deprecated. Actually, it works fine

```
   private val activityLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) {
    if (it.resultCode == "SOME_CODE") {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

To start the activity we just need to call the launch method.

```
 activityLauncher.launch(YOUR_INTENT)
```

The problem is that I want to close all activities that were starting with the same request code using the Activity.finishActivity(REQUEST_CODE).

How can we do that in this new way?

[image]

**NOTE:** I cant use Activity.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP because I want to back home without calling a new service request. I just want to reload an activity from the back stack.

*Thanks and enjoy your life.*

Comment: Did you see this [existing feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/194120495)?

Comment: No, I din't! It looks like the same problem, I'm following the task.
Thank you